# UIbutton with longpress and Touchup inside

Tags: cocoa-touch, uibutton

How to create a UIButton With two actions.

I know by using UILongPressGestureRecognizer we can perform Longpress.

But my requirement is,When I Long Press UIButton,it has to perform one action and when touch

up inside it, it has to perform another action.

Thanks.

Below is my code.

```
       UIImage *redImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabFav2.png"];
tabRedbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[tabRedbutton setImage:redImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
tabRedbutton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50,35);
redTAb = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tabRedbutton];
[tabRedbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(redbottonmethod)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



 longpressGesture1 = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressHandler:)];
longpressGesture1.minimumPressDuration =0.1;
[longpressGesture1 setDelegate:self];
longpressGesture1.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[tabRedbutton addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture1];

[longpressGesture1 release];

 - (void)longPressHandler:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

   if (longpressGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
  NSlog(@"Long press");
    }

 }


-(void)redbottonmethod
 {  

  NSlog(@"single tapped");
 }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the tap you can use UIButton's "addTarget:..." method and for the longpress you can add a gesture recognizer:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 20.0);
[btn setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(userTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
[gr addTarget:self action:@selector(userLongPressed:)];
[btn addGestureRecognizer:gr];
[gr release];

[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Of course you need to implement the 2 methods that will be called:

```
- (void)userTapped:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"user tapped");
}

- (void)userLongPressed:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"user long pressed");
}
```

Hope that helps.

=========

EDIT: It seems that you are using your button as a BarButtonItem inside a UIToolbar. So I changed my code to do the same:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // set up the button
  UIImage *redImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabFav2.png"];
  UIButton *tabRedbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  tabRedbutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  [tabRedbutton setImage:redImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  tabRedbutton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50,35);

  // set up a bar button item with the button as its view
  UIBarButtonItem *redTab = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tabRedbutton];

  // set up toolbar and add the button as a bar button item
  UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 100.0, 768.0, 40.0)];
  toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
  NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:redTab];
  [toolbar setItems:items];
  [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
 [toolbar release];

  // add tap handler to button for tap
  [tabRedbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(redbottonmethod)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  // add gesture recognizer to button for longpress
  UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressGesture1 = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressHandler:)];
  longpressGesture1.minimumPressDuration =0.1;
  [tabRedbutton addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture1];
  [longpressGesture1 release];
}
```

And the two methods that get called:

```
- (void)longPressHandler:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"Long press");
}


-(void)redbottonmethod {  
    NSLog(@"single tapped");
}
```

This code definitely works.

By the way: I noticed that in your code in the 2 methods that get called you have typo: You must use NSLog() and not NSlog(). Could that be the problem?

Comment: joern I have tried this, - (void)userLongPressed:(id)sender is not calling here.If I long press or single tapped  - (void)userTapped:(id)sender is calling everytime

Comment: That's strange. I tried the above code in a test project and it works fine. Stupid question, but are you sure you added the GestureRecognizer to the button?

Comment: No, For posting my question  I just type like this.
Thanks

Comment: yes I tried and it works for me with Bool condition.Thanks again

Comment: This one fires the event twice.