# UIButton with single press and long press events swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton

I want to trigger two action on `button click` and `button long click`. I have add a `UIbutton` in my interface builder. How can i trigger two action using `IBAction` can somebody tell me how to archive this ?

this is the code i have used for a button click

```swift
@IBAction func buttonPressed (sender: UIButton) {
....
}
```

can i use this method or do i have to use another method for long click  ?

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660282/uibutton-with-longpress-and-touchup-inside

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you want to perform any action with single tap you and long press the you can add gestures into button this way:

```
@IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, #selector (tap))  //Tap function will call when user tap on button
    let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, #selector(long))  //Long function will call when user long press on button.
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    btn.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    btn.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
}

@objc func tap() {

    print("Tap happend")
}

@objc func long() {

    print("Long press")
}
```

This way you can add multiple method for single button and you just need Outlet for that button for that..

Comment: i have multiple buttons in my ui since they all do the same this i have map them in to this method (`@IBAction func buttonPressed (sender: UIButton`)and can i add method programatically ?

Comment: Then you need to create outlet for all button and add this gestures into it.and this method will work for all buttons.

Comment: oh i have 30 buttons in my ui its a keyboard :( is there any way to archive them without using outlet ?

Comment: I think no. you have to create outlet and add gestures for all If you want to perform action with long press.:)

Comment: can we map a IBAction programatically ? so then i only have to create outlet for a one button only

Comment: yes you can use this `button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)`

Comment: when i try to add the gesture i am getting error like this `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` any idea ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80633/discussion-between-dharmesh-kheni-and-coding-is-life).

Comment: @Dharmesh I am getting this issue `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2802ec000`, I am using the following code snippet for the tapFunction, `@objc func longPress(_ btn : UIButton)
    {}`

Comment: I have multiple UIButtons in my VC as well (21 to be exact) and they all have their own IBOutlet. I assigned the gesture recognizer to each but only one will work at a time... and seeminly at random which one. 

btn1.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
...
btn21.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)

Comment: I'll answer my own question... I was iterating through all IBOutlets and assigning a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to them.. BUT I was using the same gesture recognizer for each... they all have to have their own. So I moved my "let longPress = UILongPressGesture..." code to inside the loop. Now they all work! There may be a better way. I'm all ears. Just FYI.

Answer (score 15):

```
@IBOutlet weak var countButton: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    addLongPressGesture()
}
@IBAction func countAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Single Tap")
}

@objc func longPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
        print("Long Press")
    }
}

func addLongPressGesture(){
    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress(gesture:)))
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.5
    self.countButton.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not create a custom UIButton class, create a protocol and let the button send back the info to delegte. Something like this:

```
    //create your button using a factory (it'll be easier of course)
    //For example you could have a variable in the custom class to have a unique identifier, or just use the tag property)

    func createButtonWithInfo(buttonInfo: [String: Any]) -> CustomUIButton {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.tapDelegate = self
        /*
Add gesture recognizers to the button as well as any other info in the buttonInfo

*/
        return button
    }

    func buttonDelegateReceivedTapGestureRecognizerFrom(button: CustomUIButton){
        //Whatever you want to do
    }
```