# Swift How to make a button where it takes action only after some seconds of constant tapping

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

I'm trying to make a unblock button and I'm having a hard time.

The thing is I should be able to click on the button and it only takes action after 3 seconds (for example) of constant tapping. The finger should be there otherwise it won't take action.
I already tried it with the function sleep(3) but with this function I can just tap once on the button and it takes action after 3 seconds, and that's not what I'm looking for.

Can someone help me?

Best,
Raquel

Comment: UILongPressGestureRecognizer. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilongpressgesturerecognizer/1616423-minimumpressduration

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859203/uibutton-with-single-press-and-long-press-events-swift