# Swift UIButton titleColor change when highlighted?

Tags: swift, xcode, colors, uibutton, title

I would like to titleColor of my UIBUtton to change when the user taps on the button, with the below code currently the color of the UIBUtton title changes if the user press and hold on the button, however, not when tapped quickly, could you please let me know what do I need to change in the below code to make the titleColor change upon a tap detection only:

```
    var resetFiltersButton: UIButton = {
        
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        
        button.setTitle("Clear Filters", for: .normal)
                
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold", size: 20)
        
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        
        button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .highlighted)
        
        button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
        
        button.tag = 1
        
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return button
        
    }()

   @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        // MARK: - Clear Filters button pressed:
        
        if sender.tag == 1 {

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try implementing that inside the `buttonPressed` function?

```
@objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        

      sender.setTitleColor(color: UIColorUI, for: UIControl.State)

}
```

Comment: I just tried and it is still the same outcome, this is weird!

Comment: Have you tried changing the type of the button? `UIButton(type: .custom)`

Comment: Yes I did again color is only changing when I tap and hold rather than just tapping.

Comment: Try changing the action and add  UITapGestureRecognizer to the button instead. Here is a link explaining that https://stackoverflow.com/a/30859297/11974184

Comment: I just added a tapButtonGestureRecogniser in viewDidLoad to my UIButton and change the target to buttonTapTriggered. However, I am still getting the same outcome. The weird thing is when I tap the button the action it is required to do is triggered, however, not the setColor change method!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that you are using setTitleColor for .normal and .highlighted states.

- .normal is when the button is not clicked.
- .highlighted is while the button is being clicked on.

Instead you could:

1. Just updated the .normal color when pressed (in buttonPressed); or
2. setTitleColor for .selected for after it's clicked and handle the selection state within buttonPressed (add sender.isSelected = !sender.IsSelected)

Comment: I tired your recommendations, whereby I first deleted the button.setTitleColor for highlightedState from the button computed property, and added another setTitleColor for the button of concern inside the buttonPressed method. This changed the color of the UIButton titleColor as soon as I tapped on it rather than having to tap and hold, BUT now when the tap ends the color does not go back to the color it was on before.

Comment: I also tried the second method, whereby I modified setTitleColor for highlightedState to become for .selected. And inside of the buttonPressed method I added your recommendation sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected. The color of the button's title change now as soon as I tap on the button, however, it does not go back to its previous colour until I tap on the button again.