# How to create a long press button in TableView Cell to segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button, storyboard

I can only create my segue function from the ViewController and I must have the longPress functions in my TableViewCell. There's no way to make reference to the segue function without getting an error. How would I implement this code in the cellForRow to segue when the button is held within the TableView Cell? By the way, I'm using a storyboard.

```
@objc func longPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
            print("Long Press")
            //performSegue(withIdentifier: "toProfile", sender: self)
        }
      }

    func addLongPressGesture(){
        let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress(gesture:)))
            longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.75
            self.expandButton.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easy yet unorthodox solution but works like a charm:

Place a second button into your TableView Cell, connect your segue, and set it to hidden. Then create your IBOutlet for it, which I named SegueButton:

```
@IBOutlet weak var LongPressButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var SegueButton: UIButton!
```

Now add to your awakeFromNib:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
addLongPressGesture()
}
```

Lastly, add the long press button code:

```
@objc func longPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
            if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
                print("Segue was Successful")
                SegueButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
                }
            }

    func addLongPressGesture(){
    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress(gesture:)))
        longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.75
        self.LongPressButton.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to communicate from your button / cell back to your view controller. I suggest using a closure. It would look something like this (I haven’t tested this code)...

```
class SomeCell: UITableViewCell {

    var didLongPress: (()->Void)? = nil

    @objc func longPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
            didLongPress?() 
        }
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        didLongPress = nil
    }
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellId") as! SomeCell
        cell.didLongPress = { [weak self] in 
            self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: nil)
        }
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: That's actually pretty close to what I need! It works when I hold down the button, however it segues when I tap it too unfortunately

Comment: It is triggering the segue the instant the gesture begins hence `gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began`. Change it to `ended`.

Comment: Well I have a tap action already on this button but I switched to to 'ended' and now it only triggers on tap

Comment: Your phrasing is confusing me. Why are you adding a gesture recognizer if you have a button? If you had a button that you wanted to trigger the segue, I would call the closure as a part of your button action.

Comment: I want my button to perform a specific action when tapped and a different action when held. However, I tried your example in a completely new project and ended with the same results

Comment: So you want your button to do one thing when long pressed ("held") and another thing when tapped quickly?

Comment: Yes but I already have a tap action already made for the button

Comment: This looks like what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660282/uibutton-with-longpress-and-touchup-inside

Answer (score 0):

I set up the button inside the tableview cell to segue to one view controller when tapped and a different one when long pressed.

1) Create a delegate protocol. You can put this in the custom TableViewCell class file but not within the class itself.

```
protocol MyTableViewCellDelegate : class {
   func didTapButton ()
   func didLongPressButton ()
}
```

2) Inside the actual TableViewCell class, put the following:

```
weak var delegate: MyTableViewCellDelegate?
```

// Boilerplate code

```
@objc func didLongPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
        delegate?.didLongPressButton()
    }
}
```

Control drag your button from your tableview cell into this file. Then add the additional logic.

```
@IBAction func expandButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didLongPress))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
    delegate?.didTapButton()        
}
```

In your main ViewController file, inside cellForRowAt:

```
cell.delegate = self
```

Then somewhere outside the ViewController's class logic, add the following to conform to your delegate protocol and perform your segues:

```
extension ViewController: MyTableViewCellDelegate {
    func didTapButton() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toInfoSegue", sender: self)
}
    @objc func didLongPressButton() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toProfileSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it has something to do with the segue being able to access the tap on the storyboard but it still isn't working unfortunately

Comment: I tested this in a project and it is working. How did you create your segues?  I did a ctrl-drag from the main view controller (with the tableview) to the two other view controllers. Also, what error messages are you getting or what behaviors are you seeing?

Comment: Well I did a ctrl-drag as well but I already have a tap function in my cellForRow that I need. Although your example works when I hold the button, it works when I tap too. But I'm happy to say that I found an easy solution and posted an answer here!

Comment: To clarify: Are you looking for three possible actions on a tableview cell? 1) Something happens when you select the row. 2) Something else happens when you tap a button within the row? 3) Something else happens when you long press the same button in the row? Not sure what you mean by "tap function" (on the row or the button?) YOu can have all three; just need to know what you're looking for.

Comment: In case this helps, I created a Github repo to show the code above in context. https://github.com/IosStever/Stackoverflow05112020